# $ZTIME(T(n))$ complexity $RTIME(T(n))$

Tags: cc.complexity-theory

$RTIME(T(n))$ is defined as:

Every language $L$ for which there is a probabilistic
$TM$ $M$  **running in $T(n)$** time such that
$x \in L ⇒ Pr[M(x) = 1] ≥ 2/3 $

$x \notin L ⇒ Pr[(x) = 1] = 0$

Where, $ZTIME(T(n))$ defined as:

All the languages $L$ s.t. there is an
**expected-time $O(T (n))$** $TM$ $M$ such that for every input $x$, whenever $M$ halts on $x$, the output $M(x)$ it produces is exactly $f_{L}(x)$.

Why does $ZTIME(T(n))$ defined over expected-time and $RTIME(T(n))$ defined over the running time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because if you define Zero-error time as running in strictly $O(T(n))$, then you would just get deterministic $O(T(n))$-time. (Why? Because then every choice of random bits suffices, so just pick the string $0^{T(n)}$ and simulate the machine to get the right answer). In particular, if you define $ZPP$ as zero-error with running time strictly bounded by a polynomial you just get your good old class $ZPP=P$. Simply put, if you have randomness but zero error, then you have to allow for *some* leeway in computation time, or you won't get an interesting computational class.

By contrast, you are free to define $RP$ as operating in **expected** polynomial time instead of strictly bounded time, but it won't change anything; you just get the normal class $RP$ (Why? Excercise!)

Hence $ZPP$ is to $RP$ a bit like $P$ is to $NP$ because if you take $P$ and $NP$ and say

- The running time is expected polynomial time instead of strictly polynomially bounded, and
- The error is one-sided bounded by $\frac{1}{3}$ instead of one-sided unbounded

then you obtain the classes $ZPP$ and $RP$. According to Arora and Barak, that makes the theorem $ZPP=RP\cap coRP$ surprising, because the analogous statement, $P=NP\cap coNP$, is not known (or expected).